# Button to delete row in a table using PHP and MySQL is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have page where there is a delete button to delete a row in a table. But the button is not working.

How can I fix the issue? I am giving my code below:

HTML

```
<td style="border:dotted 1px #999999; text-align:center">
        <a href="delete.php?nd_id=<?php echo $row['ND_ID'];?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000" title="Delete">
                        <strong><img src="images/cross-icon.png" width="18" height="18" /></strong></a></td>
```

PHP

```
require_once('../db_config.php');
$DateTime = gmdate('D d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime('+6 hours')); 
$DateAdd = gmdate('d-M-Y', strtotime('+6 hours'));

error_reporting(0);
ob_start();
session_start();

$username  = $_SESSION['username'];
$usertype  = $_SESSION['usertype'];

setcookie("user", "$username", time()+3600);
if($usertype == "admin") {  

    //...

    if($_GET['nd_id']) {
        $ND_ID=$_GET['nd_id'];
        $ND_ID = mysql_escape_String($ND_ID);
        print_r("$ND_ID");exit;
        $deleteUser = "delete from user_info where nd_id = '$ND_ID'";
        if (!mysql_query($deleteUser)) {
            die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
        }
        else {
            $successmassage = "User Row  Deleted";
            echo $successmassage;
        }
    }
    
    //...
}
```

Comment: Where is html of button?

Comment: please provide your html code to

Comment: change `if($_GET['nd_id'])` to `if(isset($_GET['nd_id']))`

Comment: Here is the html code @MahaDev: <td style="border:dotted 1px #999999; text-align:center">
         <a href="delete.php" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000" title="Delete">
                         <strong><img src="images/cross-icon.png" width="18" height="18" /></strong></a></td>

Comment: So from where you passing `nd_id` in your html code?

Comment: `href="delete.php?nd_id=something"`

Comment: here is my html code where i am passing the nd_id @vp_arth :  <td style="border:dotted 1px #999999; text-align:center">
         <a href="delete.php?nd_id=<?php echo $row['ND_ID'];?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000" title="Delete">
                         <strong><img src="images/cross-icon.png" width="18" height="18" /></strong></a></td>

Comment: so, update your question with this

Comment: Updated The Html part @vp_arth

Comment: That's not HTML its PHP. "not working" is not a useful diagnostic.

Comment: thanks for you suggestion @symcbean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print_r("$ND_ID");exit;
```

Why you added `exit;` over here? Your delete query will never work because exit will stop the execution of code after `print_r("$ND_ID");`

**UPDATE:** Please go through below points

1) `print_r` always used to print array and `$ND_ID` is not array so you can use echo like `echo $ND_ID;`

2) data type for nd_id column is string or int? if it's an int you dont need to wrap it with quotes like `'$ND_ID'` in your query you can just write `WHERE nd_id = $ND_ID`

3) When you clicking delete button, check the url wheather the value of `nd_id` is being passed or not like `delete.php?nd_id= OR delete.php?nd_id=any_value`

4) if value is being passed in `delete.php`, then echo it in php code as I said in 1st point

5) change your code `if($_GET['nd_id'])` to `if(isset($_GET['nd_id']))` as Frayne Konok said

Comment: I commented the exit; code.i used it to check if the value of the ND_id in the browser.But the value does not appear in the browser.@User7

Comment: because you are not passing `nd_id` from your html code so it will print nothing in the browser ofcourse

Comment: You have to pass `nd_id` from your html code like `<a href="delete.php?nd_id=id_value" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000" title="Delete">`

Comment: I just added the code & pass the nd_id,Here is the code but still not working @User7 : <td style="border:dotted 1px #999999; text-align:center">
         <a href="delete.php?ND_ID=<?php echo $row['ND_ID'];?>" style="text-decoration:none; color:#000" title="Delete">
                         <strong><img src="images/cross-icon.png" width="18" height="18" /></strong></a></td>

Comment: `delete.php?ND_ID=<?php echo $row['ND_ID'];?>` don't use caps `ND_ID` if you using `$_GET['nd_id']` in your php code because it's case sensitive.

Comment: Change your code to `delete.php?nd_id=<?php echo $row['ND_ID'];?>`

Comment: I change ND_ID to nd_id.But still not working.The button is nor deleting any row in the table.@User7

Comment: I have gone through your UPDATE anwer. When I am clicking delete button, the url value of nd_id is being passed.So what should i do now @User7.The URL : delete.php?nd_id=

Comment: `delete.php?nd_id=` Your `$row['ND_ID']` obvious empty while you render the page.

Comment: Ya vp_arth is right. I think you have no idea about GET, POST etc. Please do some research on that.

Comment: If your url is like `delete.php?nd_id=` it means no value is being passed and you will get `$_GET['nd_id'] = ''` so no row will be deleted and if your url is like `delete.php?nd_id=2` it means you will get `$_GET['nd_id'] = 2` so row which `nd_id is 2` will be deleted. Hope now you understand the issue.

Comment: the issue has been solved.The problem was in html code.in passing the nd_id value.thanks  @User7